# How can I find all possible square submatrices of a given non-square matrix?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, algebraic-manipulation

Lets say the non-square matrix is $n \times r$ where $n > r$ (# of rows is greater than # of columns). I'd like to find all $r \times r$ submatrices. What is really required is that I have to find and have all square submatrices simultaneously in order to compare their determinants at the same time. Here is the $6 \times 4$ matrix that I have. I need to find all fifteen $4 \times 4$ submatrices.

\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & -\text{Sin}\left[\theta _C\right] l_G & -\text{Sin}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & 0 \\
 0 & \text{Cos}\left[\theta _C\right] l_G & \text{Cos}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & 0 \\
 -\text{Sin}\left[\theta _B\right] l_C & 0 & \text{Sin}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & 0 \\
 \text{Cos}\left[\theta _B\right] l_C & 0 & -\text{Cos}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & 0 \\
 0 & \text{Sin}\left[\theta _C\right] l_G & \text{Sin}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & -\text{Sin}\left[\theta _F\right] l_G \\
 0 & -\text{Cos}\left[\theta _C\right] l_G & -\text{Cos}\left[\theta _D\right] l_C & \text{Cos}\left[\theta _F\right] l_G \\
\end{array}

Comment: Please include a _Mathematica_-formatted version of your matrix. You are less likely to get an answer if the answerer needs to re-type everything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Subsets[mat, {4}]
```

Replace `mat` with your matrix.

Or, more generally:

```
subMatrices[mat_List] := Subsets[mat, Dimensions[mat][[{2}]]]
```

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it does not work in a MatrixForm. It is just working when I Flatten the matrix, but it turns the matrix into an array of 48 elements!